# In Laravel what is the scenario of Queueing A Cookie For The Next Response

Tags: cookies, laravel, response

I'm reading the documentation of Laravel. I'm really confused by setting
`cookies` in Laravel in queue. At this point [Queueing A Cookie For The Next Response](http://laravel.com/docs/requests) I'm confused, can anybody tell me some scenarios I could apply this.

Comment: From the docs it sounds like you are creating a cookie **to be attached to** the response to the current request, but the method allows you to do so before that response has been created.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple, if you need to set a cookie before you have the response then you should queue it so that when the response will be sent, the cookie will be attached with the response automatically. For example, normally you'll attach the cookie with response like this

```
$response = Response::make('Hello World');
$response->withCookie(Cookie::make('name', 'value', $minutes));
```

Now, think that you don't have the response on your hand yet and you want to attach a cookie with the response, so in this case you just queue a cookie using

```
Cookie::queue($name, $value, $minutes);
```

So, whenever the response will be sent, the queued cookie will be attached with the response and will be sent along with the response automatically, in other words, any queued cookie will b automatically attached with the response, so you can queue a cookie to be sent with the response and whenever the response will be sent, the queued cookie will be sent too and you don't have to manually attach the cookie with the response.

Maybe you can think something like this:

```
Step-1: You are in a before filter
Step-2: You determined to send a cookie with the response later so queue it here
Step-3: You are in the Controller and finally you did something like

return View:make(...);
```

Laravel will check if there is any cookie queued, if it finds any cookie in the queue then Laravel will attach the cookie with the response and will be sent with response automatically.

Comment: now i know the queue is for set the cookie in advance , what about  if i pushed  more than one cookie in the queue ,then how the auto attach will do when a response is going to be send ?

Comment: Same as with one queue.